# Getting a 'FileNotFoundError'

Tags: python, file-not-found

I'm new to Python and I'm currently learning online on how to use Python for Data Analysis and Visualization. I have already taken a Python Basics course, and now I'm on the next step.

I've been trying to follow along with the coding on a lecture entitled 'Reading and Writing Text Files'. I'm trying to build a dataframe from a csv file, but I keep getting the 'FileNotFoundError'. I have saved the csv file in my c drive in a folder called Python Examples, but python cannot find the document.

In Jupyter Notebook, I've even tried inputting the correct file path in the code, but comes out with a different error, a 'Unicode' error. Here's what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

dframe = pd.read_csv('lec25.csv')
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError` means just what it says -- the file was not found.  Since you're using a plain filename without specifying a full path, it will look in the current directory (which is not necessarily the same directory where the python script is located).

Comment: If you want to see the current directory, use this code: `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Thanks for this John! I'll make a note of it.

Answer (score 0):

This line assumes the csv is in your working directory

```
dframe = pd.read_csv('lec25.csv')
```

If it is not, provide a full path or relative path

```
dframe = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Python Examples\lec25.csv')
```

Comment: Ah! I forgot to include the r' in the full path. It works now! Thanks for your help Cory!